# unique value in a list on substring python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Need to remove duplicate values based on first part before - as shown below.

```
Input:   
 a=['abc-123','abc-345','def-234']
Expected Output:
 a=['abc-123','def-234']
```

I can do below to get only unique values without any substring part, but not able to make the substring to use & remove duplicates & keep only first occurrence.

```
list(set(a))
```

Comment: If you want to remove duplicates of only the first part, then you have to do some work to separate the strings, or to recognize only that first part.  I don't see where you're stuck with that; please post the code that's giving you trouble, rather than an inapplicable one-liner that ignores that base problem.

Comment: Loop through the list, and get the first part of the string. Check if it's in the set. If it is, skip this element. If it's not, add this element to the output list, and add the first part to the set.

Comment: Be more clear on what you want to accomplish. When exactly should you remove a string and when not?

Comment: @DanteCulaciati He just wants the first string with each unique prefix.

Comment: @Barmar Ok, thanks, was asking just in case he wanted something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I would write it:

```
seen = set()
out = []
for elem in a:
    prefix = elem.split('-')[0]
    if prefix not in seen:
        seen.add(prefix)
        out.append(elem)
```

And here's a one-liner:

```
seen = set()
[x for x in a if not (x.split('-')[0] in seen or seen.add(x.split('-')[0]))]
```

If you're using Python >= 3.8, there's the walrus operator, so you don't need to call `split` twice:

```
[x for x in a if not ((prefix := x.split('-')[0]) in seen or seen.add(prefix))]
```

Comment: You call split function twice at the same time and their result is same.
Do you have any idea to avoid the problem? (I can't come up with any ideas)

Answer (score 3):

How about this one(sorry that i coudln't implement one-line)

```py
head = [_a.split("-")[0] for _a in a]
index = [i for i, item in enumerate(head) if not item in head[:i]]
result = [a[i] for i in index]
```

Comment: Can someone please explain to me what the `if not item in head[:i]` line does?

Comment: Heads are checked in order from the beginning, and by using head [: i], you can check if the same head appeared before the element you are currently paying attention to.